# match UI with defferent resolution in android

Tags: android, android-layout

my android app runs on my mobile device correctly.

but the size of elements dose not change in tablet or another device with different resolution.
they are shown small .
i think my app should be able to fit to different resolution.but i do not know how can i do?
i write some my cod below.
their size do not change.

```
      <View
    android:id="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
      />
   <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_first"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view_top"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1" 
    />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_number"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner_first"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner_first"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="phone" >


   </EditText>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Create some dimens.xml files for different screen size, or use `WeightSum` and `layout_weight` in your parent and child views.

Answer (score 3):

Use dimension resources:

For example:

```
android:layout_width="250dp"
```

This must be changed to:

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/mycustomwidth"
```

Want to know how to define custom width for each device resolution?

Go and thoroughly learn about "dimens.xml" file and much more from Android official guide [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html%E2%80%8EQ_smhSw&bvm=bv.61965928,d.cGU).

Comment: @user3374618: You may want to accept my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

you must create  dimensions files 
in each file you put values used in ech device .
for example you create values-xlarge in it create dimen.xml file .
values-hdpi, values-xhdpi ...